# $pull from array in document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to $pull from an array within a mongodb document.

The document has the structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ee62ef688b41ff072b934b"), 
    "pictures" : [ 
        {
            "url" : "...", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("54ee6303688b41ff072b934d") 
        }, 
        { 
            "url" : "...", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("54ee6304688b41ff072b934e")
        }, 
        { 
            "url" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("54ee6304688b41ff072b934f") 
        } 
    ]
}
```

I tried the update object

```
var update = { $pull: { pictures: {$elemMatch: {_id:req.params.picid } } } }

db.activity.update({_id: new ObjectId(req.params.id)}, update)
```

which returns writeresult: 1, but the picture is never removed.

ps I am using node, hense the req.params.picid

Comment: And what exactly do you pass as a value of `req.params.picid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator acts as a query document in itself and is also considered against every element of the array so [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is not needed:

```
var update = { 
   "$pull": { "pictures": { "_id": new ObjectId(req.params.picid) } }
};
```

You also need to cast your "string" from request params to an `ObjectId`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I tried a bunch of combinations, I somehow missed this one.